# How to jump and fall in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am coding a game jump in Unity. How can I jump (move) like in the Jupiter jump game, so that at a touch my hero will fall at high speed?

```
###
public float forceFly;
void Update () {
    rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, 1) forceFly);

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){

        // ?
    }
```

Comment: Please take time to format your code and post the relevant code before asking a question. Also post example of what Jupiter jump game is for those without knowledge of it.

Answer (score 0):

This question is horribly structured, and it really looks like you didn't even try. What you'll need to do is get the current position of the object by its transform.

```
gameObject.transform.position
```

and apply vector math on it. In this case you're wanting to move the Y axis up (to move into the air). A very simple implementation of this would be like so:

```
gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + forceFly, transform.position.z);
```

where forcefly is the amount that you'll "jump" every second.